# In Angular unit testing, how to clean-up $timeout promises so they don't persist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, timeout

I have a series of unit tests. One of the controllers is setting a `$timeout` promise which executes every 1000 ms (it invokes its own function, so it behaves like an $interval, continues executing every 1 second as long as the controller is being viewed). However, when the controller is destroyed (user navigates to another view), the `$timeout.cancel` is called accurately, thus the self-invoking ceases to continue.

But when running unit tests, for some reason after the test for this controller is executed, the $destroy is never triggered.

So when second unit test is run (in this case a unit test for a directive), which also uses `$timeout.flush(...)`, it is activating the $timeout promise in the unassociated controller!

But I don't know how to force the controller to $destroy after its unit tests are completed, or how to nuke $timeout to remove/cancel all promises before starting the other unit tests.

As a result, it's causing a conflict between the two unit tests, where one has unexpected behavior that is causing it to fail.

Any suggestions?

**[Edit] Solution:** By adding `scope.$destroy()` to all our controller and directive unit tests, we went from 30 seconds of unit test execution time to 6 seconds! And the $timeout conflict no longer appears.

```
afterEach(function () { 
    scope.$destroy(); //directive, or controller: $scope.$destroy();
});
```

Comment: What *I* am using is an `afterEach()` block that does `scope.$destroy()`. If you clean the timeout when the controller receives the `'$destroy'` event, it should work. Moreover, in cases like this, I write one extra test case making sure that the timeout was cleaned indeed.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I think that might be all I need, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to avoid creating real timeouts while unit-testing. That would require injecting mock of `$timeout` service when instantiating controllers, but provides more control over asynchronous operations based on timeouts during unit-testing. In simplest case when there is no need to test timeout callbacks `$timeout` mock can be very simple (example uses Jasmine):

```
describe('MainCtrl', function() {
var $scope = null;
var ctrl = null;
var mockedTimeout = function() {
  console.log('Timeout is mocked');
}
mockedTimeout.cancel = function() {
  console.log('Timeout is cancelled');
}

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
    $scope: $scope,
    $timeout: mockedTimeout
  });
}));
});
```

Here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/SC2aptl45BT3bg9FuJWP?p=preview) that shows complete test setup in action

Comment: I looked at your plunker, and I noticed the use of "$scope.$destroy" in the test. Now I realize I can just call this myself to force the destruction of the controller. Thanks!

Comment: Update: By adding `afterAll(function () { scope.$destroy(); });` to all our controller and directive unit tests, we went from 30 seconds execution time to 6 seconds! And the $timeout conflict no longer appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `$timeout` service when instantiating controllers and use the `timeout.flush()` to get the callback executed and test.
Updated [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2KkxE2aB2bWfmbv7ouYx?p=preview) with real $timeout service.